# sql db2 - add 1 month to string field cast as date

Tags: sql, db2, syntax-error

I have string field at my DB and it has a date in it.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT 
        ADD_MONTHS(CAST(obj.gn_exe_param_val AS DATE ), -1) as nend_date1,
        month(ADD_MONTHS(CAST( obj.gn_exe_param_val AS DATE ), -1)) as tmonth,
        year(ADD_MONTHS(CAST( obj.gn_exe_param_val AS DATE ), -1)) as tyear,
        year(cast(obj.gn_exe_param_val as date))*100 +
            MONTH(cast(obj.gn_exe_param_val as date)) as first_deposit
FROM tbl1 obj1, tbl4 obj
```

Im looking for the right way to cast this field and add 1 month to it.
I tried this without the `ADD_MONTH` function:

```
CAST( obj.gn_exe_param_val AS DATE )  - 1 )
```

But then I got this error:

> Error: SQL0182 - A date, time, or timestamp expression not valid.
>   (State:S1000, Native Code: FFFFFF4A)

Comment: db2 and sql server are not the same product.

Comment: The problem is for DB2 database

Comment: I think the error is clear.  You may think the column has valid dates, but it does not.

Comment: Please give us more complete sql. You are missing a '(' in the example you wrote, is it a copy/paste mistake ? Otherwise it's the cause of your error.

Comment: Does any of the requests ```SELECT CAST( obj.gn_exe_param_val AS DATE ) FROM tbl1``` and ```SELECT CAST( obj.gn_exe_param_val AS DATE ) FROM tbl4``` give you the same error ?

Comment: I looking for way to remove the function "ADD_MONTHS" .

Comment: Yes, I know but it's a diagnostic request. If ```SELECT CAST( tbl1.gn_exe_param_val AS DATE ) FROM tbl1``` fails it means you have one or more bad values (not convertible to date) in your datas. If the resquest doesn't fail the problem is something else. (Edit, replaced "obj" by "tbl1")

Comment: SELECT CAST( tbl1.gn_exe_param_val AS DATE ) FROM tbl1 - Workes fine

Comment: Well, DB2 supports the use of date math syntax, but you can't get away from specifying the unit: `CAST(tbl1.gn_exe_param_val AS DATE) - 1 MONTH`.  If possible, you should convert the string column to date (for a number of reasons, but should also save you space)

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse according to the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0053628.html) there is actually subtile differences between arithmetic and add_month, so the choice between the two syntaxes is important. And I agree, the column should be date typed.

Comment: @firetonton - the behavior in the case of `ADD_MONTHS(...)` is potentially very dangerous, because it can end up changing your dates unexpectedly with repeated calls: `'2015-01-28'` -> `'2015-02-28'` -> `'2015-03-31'`.  Dates(/Timestamps) should be considered a positive, contiguous-range type, and queried with an exclusive upper-bound (`<`); there should be no need for an end-of-month date in the first place (instead choosing less than the start of the next month, which saves headaches dealing with leap years, too).

Comment: Thank you very much, It worked!